# Rejected edit review

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I made [a fairly minor edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12916407) to an answer that fixed an issue with invalid syntax ordering to an otherwise correct response.

The edit was rejected, for what I feel are invalid reasons.

I could have suggested the edit as a comment on the answer, but I feel this would have added unnecessary clutter. Am I wrong here and what recourse do I have to have it approved?

Answer (score -1):

The answerer has a silver [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) badge. A user who has a badge in a language tag should know the syntax rules of that language.

In other words, **downvote and comment.**

Comment: Unless he made a simple typo, which is likely. Can you explain why downvoting and commenting is a better solution than just fixing an obvious typo?

Comment: @CodyGray Because it's the answerer's responsibility to get the syntax right.

Answer (score -5):

The problem with fixing errors like that is it might hide the user's actual problem, which obfuscates it from anyone trying to answer it.

If I had `public Sring myDumbMistake` and you edited it out, I would be confused and so would the answerers. Instead, post a comment or an answer in case that's the root of their problem.

Comment: The thing being edited was an answer, not a question.

Comment: Whoops. Serves me right for using SO on my phone.